# How to capture front photo in android lock screen

Tags: java, android

I am developing custom lockscreen project in android studio.So I am going to capture front camera when click button on lockscreen without camera preview.
But I don't know how to start.I want to know how to take a picture without camera preview in lock status.
Please help me.

Comment: please have a look http://www.41post.com/3794/programming/android-take-a-picture-without-displaying-a-preview